# Air travel with goldfish

Tags: airport-security, pets

I know there are plenty of options for travelling with cats and dogs, but is travelling with a fish something that's possible? Back in the day, it probably wasn't an issue, but safety regulations regarding liquids are a bit tighter nowadays.

Comment: Where are you travelling from and to?

Comment: While it may depend on the airline, I’m pretty sure you will need to use the services of a specialised company for this. You may try to call the airline, to confirm, and they may have suggestions of which company can arrange this for you.

Comment: @lambshaanxy From Lisbon, Portigal. The destination and airline aren't settled yet, we're looking at aoptions.

Comment: @jcaron In the US the TSA allows hand-carrying live fish: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/live-fish

Comment: @lambshaanxy Wooooo I would not have thought that for a second. Interesting. Wonder if other agencies do the same? Most are not as transparent as the TSA on this topic so it's probably a difficult information to find.

Comment: USDA doesn't list live fish under their traveling with pets section, but does note that Goldfish are susceptible to disease which they're on the lookout for. More info [here](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/ourfocus/animalhealth/animal-and-animal-product-import-information/live-animal-imports/aquatic-animals/fish-eggs-gametes). There's a vet clearance form, but it's for a commercial import. You might want to contact them anyway.